# Trouble integrating Tiny Slideshow

Tags: javascript

http://dev.llnd.org/#/art/time-compression
The slideshow script I'm trying to integrate has an error: i get
**Uncaught ReferenceError: time is not defined**

```
i.onload=new Function(this.n+'.le('+s+','+c+')');
```

I've already commented out most other scripts, but I can't comment out the jquery, otherwise the whole site collapses. The code is not very clear to me and I'm not sure where to trace the error to. I'll add a bounty as soon as I can.

The  code comes from here http://dev.llnd.org/js/llnd.js

Comment: Can you post more of that code?  Also there's nothing there that has anything to do with "jQuery".

Comment: http://dev.llnd.org/js/llnd.js the code comes from here

Comment: Wow the author of that "Tiny Slide Show" should make sure that *Javascript: The Good Parts* is on his Santa list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the string "time-compression".  I don't know where that's coming from, but it should be "time_compression" or "timeCompression".  The string has to look like an identifier (a Javascript identifier, in particular), or else that abominable code in the "Tiny Slide Show" will fall over.

*edit* — the thing to change is the `<ul>` element that currently has the "id" value "time-compression".